# How do fix this springboot error : Connection read-only mode is not enforceable after the connection has been established

Tags: sql, spring-boot

In my Springboot 2.3.0 application, I'm getting this WARNING in the log file intermittently and would like to stop logging them.

I understand that this is just a warning and can be ignored. But Is there a property that I can add to application.properties and stop logging this in the log file.

````
To enforce a read only connection, set the read-only data source or connection property. ERRORCODE=4474, SQLSTATE=01000 ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is just a WARNING, I enabled ERROR log level for this particular package, so that WARNINGS are not shown in the log.